# How to parse an object instead of an array with retrofit2

Tags: android, rest, kotlin, retrofit2

So I'm a beginning android dev and I'm using retrofit2 to perform a GET request to my API. However I'm getting a "expected begin_array but was begin_object".

I've tried reading up on the issue on many websites but none of them was helpful (for me) including the documentation of retrofit.

I tried creating a POJO class in kotlin and following this tutorial: https://www.freshbytelabs.com/2018/05/how-to-fix-expected-beginarray-but-was.html.

But I'm simply lost when the author uses variables that I don't see declared in his code. So copy/pasting the example didn't work. Maybe because I'm plain stupid, but I'd appreciate any help.

The JSON expected response (tested with postman):

```
{
    "value": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "uniqueId": "1b97653d-bafe-461f-b609-72ab6795737f",
            "code": "NL",
            "description": "something",
            "isActive": true,
            "dateCreated": "2019-04-12T22:41:28.4966667",
            "dateModified": "2019-04-12T22:41:28.4966667",
            "dateExpired": "9999-12-31T00:00:00",
            "timestamp": "AAAAAAAAB9E=",
            "responseUserList": []
        }
    ],
    "success": true,
    "errorCode": null,
    "errorMessage": null
}
```

This is my main:

```
var restLanguageService = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://30cookweb20190412110132.azurewebsites.net/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
        var service = restLanguageService.create(RequestInterface::class.java)

        var call = service.getAllLanguages()

        call.enqueue(object: Callback<List<RequestInterface>>
        {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<RequestInterface>>, response: Response<List<RequestInterface>>)
            {
                var restLanguages = response.body().toString()
                if (!response.isSuccessful)
                {
                    for (RestLanguage in restLanguages)
                        textView.text = "Code: " + response.code()
                    return
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<RequestInterface>>, t: Throwable)
            {
                textView.text = t.message
            }
        })
```

My Interface:

```
interface RequestInterface
{
    @GET("api/language/getalllangaugesasync")
    fun getAllLanguages(): Call<List<RequestInterface>>
}
```

My data class:

```
data class LanguageResponse(
    @SerializedName("errorCode")
    @Expose
    private val errorCode: Any,
    @SerializedName("errorMessage")
    @Expose
    private val errorMessage: Any,
    @SerializedName("success")
    @Expose
    private val success: Boolean,
    @SerializedName("languageValue")
    @Expose
    private val value: List<Value>
)
```

This is my string printed in textView:

"expected begin_array but was begin_object at line 1 column 2 path$"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your interface should be returning the response which according to the details should be

```
    interface RequestInterface
{
    @GET("api/language/getalllangaugesasync")
    fun getAllLanguages(): Call<LanguageResponse>
}
```

*instead of*

```
    interface RequestInterface
{
    @GET("api/language/getalllangaugesasync")
    fun getAllLanguages(): Call<List<RequestInterface>>
}
```

Comment: Thanks! You're absolutely right. However, when I do this, my object in the call enqueue becomes invalid with the following statement: 

"Object is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract fun onResponse(call: Call<List<LanguageResponse>!>!, response: Response<List<LanguageResponse>!>!): Unit defined in retrofit2.Callback".

How come, this changes? The overrides are also now in red squigly lines.

Comment: Nevermind my earlier comment. It's without errors now, however I still do get the same problem now that I've updated my interface and main:

```interface RequestInterface
{
    @GET("api/language/getalllangaugesasync")
    fun getAllLanguages(): Call<List<LanguageResponse>>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it. Not only was Taranjit Kaur correct in his assessment, but also I've had this code:

```
if (!response.isSuccessful)
                {
                    for (RestLanguage in restLanguages)
                        textView.text = "Code: " + response.code()
                    return
                }
```

The exclamation mark made me search all day for my error.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: It's her  assessment :p and  if the answer helped you, may be you can mark it as correct answer ..

Comment: Ah I'm sorry in my assumption.

Comment: No worries.. Happy to help